Drools: nested exists
I want to have a nested exists in my rule, but when I run it I get a mismatched input error. I am trying to find if, for an object with 2 lists, there exists an object in list 1 and an an object in list 2 such that they are equivalent.
Here are the relevant objects:
public class A {
  List<B> bList;
  List<C> cList;
}

public class B {
  String name;
}

public class C {
  String id;
}

(B == C if B.name == C.id)
Is there a Drools-only solution or workaround for what I want to do?
Here is my rule (causes mismatched input error).
rule "find B-C match"

when
$a: A(bList != null && cList != null)
  exists $b: B(
    exists $c: C($b.name == $c.id)
    from $a.cList)
  from $a.bList
then
System.out.println("A has a match");
// do other stuff
end


If you only want to verify that there exists at least one item in CList that matches a bList item via the b.name == c.id criteria, you'd use an exists(...) like this:
rule "example 1"
when
  A( $bList: bList, $cList )
  B( $name: name) from $bList
  exists( C( id == $name ) from $cList )
then
  System.out.println("B == C exists!")
end

Alternatively, if you need references to the matching B and C instances for some operation, you can omit the exists clause.
rule "example 2"
when
  A( $bList: bList, $cList )
  $b : B( $name: name) from $bList
  $c: C( id == $name ) from $cList
then
  System.out.println("B == C exists!")
  // you can now reference $b and $c directly
end

The caveat for both of these examples is that they will fire for each match.
For example, let's say your object A looks something like this:
A {
  bList: [
    { name: "1" }, // 0
    { name: "2" }, // 1
    { name: "3" }  // 2
  },
  cList: [
    { id: "4" }, // 0
    { id: "3" }, // 1
    { id: "3" }, // 2
    { id: "1" }  // 3
  ]
}

If you fire the "Example 1" rule (with exists) against this input, it'll fire 2 times:

once for the bList item at index 0, which matches to cList item at index 3
once for the bList item at index 2, which matches to both the cList items at indices 1 and 2.

Since you're using exists, as long as there is at least one match in cList, the rule will fire -- that's why you only fire once for name: "3".
Now, if you fire the "Example 2" rule, it'll actually fire 3 times:

once for bList[0] which matches cList[3]
once for bList[2] and its pair at cList[1]
once for bList[2] and its pair at cList[2]

Since we've not used exists, the rule will trigger for each pair of items that matches. This is useful when you need to do operations for each pair, but less so if you're just trying to figure out if there's at least once such pair.

What if we only want to check that there is at least one matching pair? In english, "there is at least one item in bList whose name is equal to the id of an item in cList". We only want the rule to fire once, not once for each bList match, or once for each matching pair.
If we want to do it as stated, we could write a rule that makes use of accumulate -- what this operation does is collect all items which match some complex comparison ... this this case we'd effectively collect all matching B-C pairs. Then we'd check that the resulting list had size >= 1.
That sounds like a lot of work when we only want at least one match -- and it is. It's a lot simpler to just re-purpose the "example 1" rule and have it only fire once.
rule "example 1 - only once"
when
  not( String(this == "example1") )

  A( $bList: bList, $cList: cList )
  B( $name: name ) from $bList
  exists( C( id == $name ) from $cList )
then 
  // do your operations here
  insert( "example1" )
end

This is an old Drools trick; when you trigger your rule, insert something into working memory which makes it no longer valid to fire. In this case I went with a simple String but you can use any sort of object, really.
When the rule is evaluated, one of the conditions is that there's no string with text "example1" in working memory. If that condition is satisfied along with the others (there is a B=C match), then the rule triggers. After whatever business logic is done, we then insert that "example1" string into working memory. Now the rule is no longer valid to be fired, so no matter how many additional B=C pairs there are in the A object, they will not trigger additional executions of the rule.
